# MySQL query to get subtotal of unique values

Tags: mysql

I have following data: 

`+---+----+
|Key|Name|
+---+----+
|1  |Tom |
+---+----+
|2  |Tom |
+---+----+
|3  |Dan |
+---+----+
|4  |Dan |
+---+----+
|5  |Dan |
+---+----+
|6  |Dan |
+---+----+
|7  |Ken |
+---+----+
|8  |Ken |
+---+----+`

And need MySQL query to get this

`+---+----+-----------+
|Key|Name| subtotal  |
+---+----+-----------+
|1  |Tom |    2      |
+---+----+-----------+
|2  |Tom |    2      |
+---+----+-----------+
|3  |Dan |    4      |
+---+----+-----------+
|4  |Dan |    4      |
+---+----+-----------+
|5  |Dan |    4      |
+---+----+-----------+
|6  |Dan |    4      |
+---+----+-----------+
|7  |Ken |    2      |
+---+----+-----------+
|8  |Ken |    2      |
+---+----+-----------+`

the same data but with additional column showing the number of unique names, from Name column. I tried to use count(1) and group by, but result come as 3 name entries and total, but I need every single record with additional information on how many records have the same value as in column Name

Comment: What query did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: Next time you post a question, please try to format it properly using the available tools, and make sure the sample data is accurate (which it isn't this time).

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first post, and I am still figuring out how to submit formatted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.total
from your_table t1
join
(
  select name, count(*) as total
  from your_table
  group by name
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *, (sum(name)) as total from table
group by name
```

i think this resolve your problem